# how to make ttk widget glow slowly when hovered

Tags: python, tkinter, button, hover, ttk

I am trying to make my `ttk` widget glow slowly when hovered like the `messagebox` OK button.
Type this into your code editor and hover over the OK button to see what I mean by widget glowing slowly.

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("","Hover over OK button!")
```

However, the `ttk` widget immediately lights up when hovered.

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text ="Hover over me!").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

May I know how to make my `ttk` widget glow slowly when hovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ttk` you would have to create a bunch of styles and cycle through them. That would be ridiculous, and unnecessary. Using `tk` you can change the background (or any other property) on-the-fly. It's much more suited for the behavior you desire.

You don't have to use my `deque` method. You could keep incrementing some integer and resetting it. You could also do something like: `self.colors.append(self.colors.pop(0))` ~ which is basically the same thing the `deque` is doing, as a proxy. The real point here is that `after` is used to keep running a method that cycles though a list of colors, and applies whatever the current color is to the button.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque

class GlowButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        #store background color
        self.bg_idle = self.cget('background')
        
        #list of glow colors to cycle through
        self.colors    = ['#aa88aa', '#aa99aa', '#aaaaaa', '#aabbaa', '#aaccaa', '#aaddaa', '#aaeeaa', '#aaffaa']
        #deque to use as an offset
        self.col_index = deque(range(len(self.colors)))
        #eventual reference to after
        self.glow      = None
        
        #add MouseOver, MouseOut events
        self.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: self.__glow(True))
        self.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: self.__glow(False))
        
    def __glow(self, hover):
        if hover:
            #get rotation offset
            ofs = self.col_index.index(0)
            #apply color from rotation offset
            self.configure(background=self.colors[ofs])
            #if the offset has not reached the end of the color list
            if ofs != len(self.colors)-1:
                #rotate
                self.col_index.rotate(1)
                #do all of this again in 50ms
                self.glow = self.after(50, self.__glow, hover)
        else:
            #kill any expected after
            self.after_cancel(self.glow)
            #rewind
            self.col_index.rotate(-self.col_index.index(0))
            #reset to idle color
            self.configure(background=self.bg_idle)

        
root = tk.Tk()
GlowButton(root, text='button', font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='#aa88aa').grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```